# List Transformation

Tags: prolog

I have a list:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

I would like to transform it into this:

```
L= [ex(1,2),ex(3,4),ex(5,6),ex(7,8)]
```

How can I effectively do this?

[edited to add:]
This is what I have so far:

```
convert( [] , S ) .
convert( [A,B|Rest] , S ) :-
  S is ( ex(A,B) | Rest ) ,
  convert(Rest)
  .
```

Comment: I am a beginner
I lost an hour trying to get it
This is my old code
convert([],S).
convert([A,B|Rest],S) :- S is (ex(A,B)|Rest), convert(Rest).

Comment: `is/2` is only needed to reduce arithmetic exceptions. You were on the right track, you just needed to move the `ex(A,B)|Rest` into the head and use the right list notation. Next time bring your code and I'll be less sarcastic and mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gosh, have you tried anything at all?

```
convert([], []).
convert([X,Y|R], [ex(X,Y)|S]) :- convert(R, S).
```

Tell your prof I said "hi".